# Python sklearn : fit_transform() does not work for GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am creating a `GridSearchCV` classifier as

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',sublinear_tf=True)),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
    ])

parameters= {}

gridSearchClassifier = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=3, verbose=1, scoring='accuracy')
    # Fit/train the gridSearchClassifier on Training Set
    gridSearchClassifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

This works well, and I can predict. However, now I want to retrain the classifier. For this I want to do a `fit_transform()` on some feedback data.

```
    gridSearchClassifier.fit_transform(Xnew, yNew)
```

But I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'fit_transform'
```

basically i am trying to `fit_transform()` on the classifier's internal `TfidfVectorizer`. I know that i can access the `Pipeline`'s internal components using the `named_steps` attribute. Can i do something similar for the `gridSearchClassifier`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call them step by step.

```
gridSearchClassifier.fit(Xnew, yNew)
transformed = gridSearchClassifier.transform(Xnew)
```

the `fit_transform` is nothing more but these two lines of code, simply not implemented as a single method for `GridSearchCV`.

#### update

From comments it seems that you are a bit lost of what GridSearchCV actually does. This is a meta-method to fit a model with multiple hyperparameters. Thus, once you call `fit` you get an estimator inside the `best_estimator_` field of your object. In your case - it is a pipeline, and you can extract any part of it as usual, thus

```
gridSearchClassifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
clf = gridSearchClassifier.best_estimator_
# do something with clf, its elements etc. 
# for example print clf.named_steps['vect']
```

you should **not** use gridsearchcv as a classifier, this is only a method of fitting hyperparameters, once you find them you should  work with `best_estimator_` instead. However, remember that **if you refit the TFIDF vectorizer, then your classifier will be useless**; you cannot change data representation and expect old model to work well, you have to refit the whole classifier once your data change (unless this is carefully designed change, and you make sure old dimensions mean exactly the same - sklearn does not support such operations, you would have to implement this from scratch).

Comment: this will refit the whole model. Exactly as would 'fit_transform'

Comment: i did gridSearchClassifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
    gridSearchClassifier = gridSearchClassifier.transform(Xtrain) and when i tried to do gridSearchClassifier.best_score_ i get the error AttributeError: best_score_ not found

Comment: is there a way like named_steps to access the internal TfIdfvectorizer?

Comment: thanks, now it makes more sense. i guess it would be better if i use the TfIdfVectorizer separately

Comment: so here is my problem. i fit the training set for my GridSearchCV object and lets say it takes 2 hours. now i want to updated the training set with some new examples. if what you are saying is correct, then i will have to fit my GridSearchCV object again on the original training set plus the new stuff. is there any way to avoid this? i would really like to just fit on the new stuff

Comment: you would need a classifier with online learning capabilities (like SGDClassifier from sklearn) and either "frozen" tfidf or modified "by hand", so previous dimensions are the same as before and you only add new ones, and manually feed last classifier as a starting point of new one with new dimensions set to 0. In general - incremental learning is not simple in production.

Answer (score 2):

@lejot is correct that you should call `fit()` on the `gridSearchClassifier`.

Provided `refit=True` is set on the `GridSearchCV`, which is the default, you can access `best_estimator_` on the fitted `gridSearchClassifier`.

You can access the already fitted steps:

```
tfidf = gridSearchClassifier.best_estimator_.named_steps['vect']
clf = gridSearchClassifier.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf']
```

You can then transform new text in `new_X` using:

```
X_vec = tfidf.transform(new_X)
```

You can make predictions using this `X_vec` with:

```
x_pred = clf.predict(X_vec)
```

You can also make predictions for the text going through the pipeline entire pipeline with.

```
X_pred = gridSearchClassifier.predict(new_X)
```

Comment: you mean like 
gridSearchClassifier.fit(Xnew, yNew) gridSearchClassifier.best_estimator_.named_steps['vect'].transform(Xnew)

Comment: i also want to use the gridSearchClassifier to get gridSearchClassifier.best_score_

Comment: basically once the fit and transform has been completed, i want to use the classifier to predict and do other things

Comment: Yes exactly. Provided `refit=True` is passed with `GridSearch(clf, params, refit=True)`, you can call transform on any of the transformation steps, or you can call predict on the final estimator step.

Comment: @AbtPst, I updated my answer with more examples of how the fitted gridSearchClassifier can be used.